# Horizontal menu not appearing

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Hey guys am new to wordpress development actually.I am trying to make my wordpress menu horizontal at the top below the title name.

## header.php

In my header file i have assigned the menus with a class which looks like

```
<nav class="mythirdclass">
<?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>
</nav>
```

And in my `style.css`

```
.mythirdclass {
float: left;
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style-type: none;
   display: inline;
}
```

But this code isnt working at all ..i want the menu to be appear in horizontal way.

Any help would be really appreciated..Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add to your style:

```
.mythirdclass li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
```

**or**

```
.mythirdclass {
  text-align: left;
}
.mythirdclass li {
  display: inline;
}
```

hope this help..good luck! ;)

Comment: see i dont have an <li> tag in my header.php

Comment: yes.. li will be created automatic by `<?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>`, just add in css my code from previous comment :)